# Slow rendering of SVG

Tags: svg

I have two different maps of floor plans as SVG files. The files are created from dwg files. One of them are rendering in an acceptable rate but the other is extremely slow.

I have checked the pts-count, and the faster SVG actually has 4 times as many, so that shouldn't be the problem. 
I have tried excluding the shadow effects with no result.
I'm using SVGO to optimise the files as well.

I also noticed straight away when I opened the (slow) dwg-file in Illustrator that it took a really long time loading when toggling the different layers and selecting them and so on.

I'm not that experienced with working with SVG's so any advice on where to start trouble shooting would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is rather broad and unspecific, an in danger of being closed for that reason. Can you add the two files so we can inspect them? Without the specific examples, there's no other option than guessing...

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't share the files. Is there anything else I can provide to help you with guessing at least?

Comment: @Ideline Yes, provide a [mcve].